# Giants i3d exporter addon

Tags: export

[image]When I install the add on it keeps saying upgrade to 2.8x why is this showing when I just want to create a map for Farming Simulator 2019 Giants editor software.

Any ideas what the issue would be?

Answer (score -1):

Because the plugin is version 7.1.0, and you need the plugin version 8.0.0, unfortunately there is no such plugin

Comment: Content should be in English language, see [answer] for more info.